# Почему при одном варианте импорта Fragment не работает ViewModelProviders а при другом функция add в FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragment

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Изучаю Android разработку по книге 21 года, но судя по всему наткнулся на устаревшую инфу и сам не могу решить проблему, 10 раз перепроверил все по учебнику верно.
Проблема заключается в следующем:

Есть `class CrimeListFragment : Fragment()`

Если `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment`
То supportFragmentManager работает корректно
Но

```
private val crimeListViewModel: CrimeListViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CrimeListViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

Уже выдает ошибку.

Если `import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`
То вышеуказанный код не ругается, однако:

```
supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit()
```

Функция add ругается что ожидает android.support.v4.app.Fragment
И я не знаю как мне реализовать обе функции для одного фрагмента, если при любом варианте импорта часть кода отпадает.
Помогите пожалуйста, в чем я ошибся?

P.S.

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Comment: У вас, видимо, путаница в зависимостях. Использовать нынче надо `androidx` зависимости. `support` зависимости использовать не надо. Покажите что у вас за библиотеки подключены.

Comment: Тесты вы наверняка не пишите, поэтому `testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+' androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2' androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'` надо бы удалить, вместе с папками `test` и `androidTest` в проекте + выше по build.gradle у вас должно быть что-то про `testInstrumentation` - это тоже лишнее в этом случае.

Comment: А вот для этих либ `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'` надо поменять на аналоги из `androidx` - тогда всё должно заработать.

Comment: implementation 'com.androidx.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

  implementation 'com.androidx.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

Так? У меня просто теперь все немного поломалось :D

Comment: Похоже на правду) а что поломалась?

Comment: AppCompatActivity я так полагаю)
'import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity' - v7 подчеркивает красным, и половину кода в mainActivity.

Comment: Добавил скрин в вопрос

Comment: Удалите красные импорты и импортируйте заново

Comment: В первую очередь попытался, но не предлагает вариантов для импорта(

Comment: А нет, я сглупил, теперь все получилось. Спасибо большое!)

Comment: Но первоначальная проблема не решилась, все осталось как было..)

Comment: Очень странно. Если у саппорт либи импорты из них не осталось - конфликтов быть не должно. Попробуйте syncProjectWithGradle выполнить.

Comment: Я синхронизировал, но еще раз зайдя в Gradle, вот что обнаружил - после того как я импортировал AppCompatActivity он снова добавил в градл старую имплементацию - implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0', и она красным шрифтом, при том что новая  'com.androidx.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' тоже осталась на месте

Comment: На самом деле вот это com.androidx.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 выглядит неправильно. Попробуйте не исправлять группу в зависимостях вручную, но просто их (либы) удалить и найти в доке правильную запись

Comment: Да, конечно, спасибо Вам)
На https://developer.android.com/ искать? 
Не могу понять там, какая именно мне нужна, совсем профан, первый раз с библиотеками мучаюсь)

Comment: Решил проблему, имплементировал implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0". Спасибо Вам большое, очень признателен)